# Best way of appending two <br> before making a new html element with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button when clicked creates a input and I want it to be separated by a space ontop and I noticed 1 `<br>` just makes it go to a new line so I wanted to add two but when I do this

```
function createInput(){

var br = document.createElement("br");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "file";

  document.body.appendChild(br);
  document.body.appendChild(br);
  document.body.appendChild(input);


}
```

It only shows up with one line down.

Comment: Don't use `<br>` to layout your page. Instead, use CSS properties like `margin`.

Comment: Your `<br>` is already added. It doesn't matter how many times you add it.

Comment: Make the second (or first) append `document.body.appendChild(br.cloneNode())` so you add a copy of the first.

Answer (score 2):

From the MDN documentation of [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference
>   to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its
>   current position to the new position (there is no requirement to
>   remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other
>   node).

Because you are appending the same element twice, the second time all it's doing is moving the element from it's current position (the end of the document) to the end of the document.  i.e.  It's not doing anything.  You need to create a 2nd br:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Or better still, as @torazaburo suggests, use CSS properties for your layout  (But one thing at a time, hey?)

Comment: Good answer,and which way would be good with css? making the button `display:inline-block` tho that would throw off anything to its right to a 2nd line. idk who down voted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-element-insertadjacenthtml)

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<br><br><input type='file'>")
```